# Django, Form Resubmit on refresh page?

Tags: django, forms

I am developing a django app, when i submit the form its works correctly but when i refresh the page the form resubmit the data again to the database  i have tried everything i can but can't seem to get this to work right

my view

```
def _article(request, article_id):
  try:
    article = Article.objects.get(pk=article_id)
    related_articles = Article.objects.filter(tags=article.tags).exclude(pk=article.pk)[:4]
    context['article'] = article
    context['related_articles'] = related_articles
    context['comments'] = article.comments_set.all().order_by('-date')[:4]
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.cleaned_data['comment']
            article.comments_set.create(comment=comment)
            return render(request,'blog/article.html',context)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()        
        context['form'] = form      
    return render(request,'blog/article.html', context)
except Exception as e:
    #write error to file
    return render(request,'blog/404.html')
```

Comment: You can store a value in cookie or session, after redirecting the post, just read the `cookie/session`, and then clear the cookie variable or value of that session.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is with the _article view. Try changing the code to this

```
def _article(request, article_id):
  if request.method == "POST":
    form = CommentForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
      comment = form.cleaned_data['comment']
      article.comments_set.create(comment=comment)
      return HttpResponseRedirect("</your/url>")
  return render(request,'blog/article.html',context))
  ................
```